# Observable transformation to handle backend server error

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators, rxjs-observables

Apologies for the newbie/dump question about RxJS, just started since I am learning Angular.

So I've created an asynchronous validator static method that calls an API service method checking the uniqueness of username in the database. The code snippets below works when the backend server is up and running. When it is not, it prints an error log message which I should be handling in the presentation component instead.

What am missing here in the transformation step to handle such generics use case to convert both `Observable<SuccessResponse>` and `Observable<ErrorResponse>` to `Observable<ValidationErrors | null>`.

**Validator**

```
static usernameUnique(service: ApiService): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: FormControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        return service.isUsernameTaken(control.value as string)
            .pipe(
                map((response: SuccessResponse) => response.data ? { taken: true } : null)
            );
    };
}
```

**ApiService**

```
isUsernameTaken(username: string): Observable<SuccessResponse | ErrorResponse> {
    return this.httpCient.get('/backend/account/checkUnique', { params: { username: username } })
                .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}

handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) : Observable<ErrorResponse> {
    // return specific payload of ErrorResponse based on error.status
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not exactly sure where you are running into an issue. If you're trying to resolve the map to ValidationErrors inside the validator, you will need to check the type. In this example I'm returning an error named "apiError" to differentiate from the "taken" error, but I'm not sure how you are choosing to handle this case in your app.

I am assuming that `ErrorResponse` contains an `error` field, and that `SuccessResponse` contains a `data` field.

```js
static usernameUnique(service: ApiService): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: FormControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    return this.isUsernameTaken(control.value as string)
      .pipe(
        map(response => {
          if ('error' in response) { // response is ErrorResponse
            return { apiError: response.error };
          }
          return response.data ? { taken: true } : null;
        })
      );
  };
```

If you are constructing actual class instances using `new ErrorResponse()` and `new SuccessResponse()` you can use `intanceof` instead of checking fields by using the `in` operator. e.g. `if (response instanceof ErrorResponse)`.

**Alternatively**, you can bubble the error back up to the validator, and handle the response in another `catchError`. I prefer this way because there is no conditional logic on the response from the api.

**Validator**

```js
static usernameUnique(service: ApiService): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: FormControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    return this.isUsernameTaken(control.value as string)
      .pipe(
        map(response => response.data ? { taken: true } : null),
        catchError((err: ErrorResponse) => of({ apiError: err.error }))
      );
  };
}
```

**ApiService**

```js
isUsernameTaken(username: string): Observable<SuccessResponse> {
  return this.http.get('/backend/account/checkUnique', { params: { username } })
    .pipe(
      map(response => response as SuccessResponse), // maps the api response to SuccessResponse
      catchError(this.handleError) // maps the error to ErrorResponse
    );
}

handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<never> {
  let errorResponse: ErrorResponse;
  // specific payload of ErrorResponse based on error.status

  return throwError(errorResponse);
}
```

Comment: The `pipe(map, catchError)` combo is what I am looking for now. Thanks a ton.